# How to know which one is the main query?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I just did an action on the query using `pre_get_posts` and it didn't work. When I removed the `$query->is_main_query()` it did work.

So, how do you know that what is the main query. I know there is the function `is_main_query`. What I am asking is there a way to tell which one you are looking at? How does WordPress know which one is the main query? If you have three or four going for different reasons such as categories, post types, pages. which is the main?

Comment: Try to answer your own Q after reading this: [You don't know Query](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-portland-2011). And this: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Comment: nope. Still didn't do it for me. Obviously the query that I was changing with pre_get_posts wasn't the main query. But then that still leaves the question. If that wasn't the main query, which one is? The loop is the standard loop. I didn't use query_posts, get_posts or wp_query. Rather the_loop does but why is that loop not the main query? Not sure I am explaining myself correctly. I don't like those little slide shows you linked to. They usually leave a lot of information. Like they are cliff notes that someone wrote up for a speech. If you miss the speech you can't follow along very well.

Comment: ps. Why did you migrate this from meta? what is the difference between the two sites?

Comment: Read the [faq] of both and you'll know. That slide is from a Lead WordPress Developer, I think [this is the presentation](http://wordpress.tv/2012/06/15/andrew-nacin-wp_query/).

Comment: After asking 37 questions I'd have thought someone knows the difference and has at least read the [faq] _briefly_ before...

Comment: avoid `query_posts`, and post code examples

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for the links. There is some very good information in them. I did not know about the WordPress.tv site. I plan on spending some time there and I signed up for the wordcamp information.

Comment: For future reference, posting relevant template/loop code would be especially helpful for defining context, and identifying details specific to your problem. @Rarst provides an excellent *general* answer, but without seeing *your actual code*, we can't help determine why the loop that you *expect* to be the main query isn't being recognized by WordPress as the main query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WP_Query->is_main_query()` method source (which function of same name calls) is very short and simple:

```
function is_main_query() {
    global $wp_the_query;
    return $wp_the_query === $this;
}
```

The main query is the query that is stored in `$wp_the_query` global. But what is that global? When WP sets up main query it stores it in two places: `$wp_the_query` and `$wp_query`. Latter is more known because that variable is what you commonly use to work with main query and what `query_posts()` changes.

However `query_posts()` works like this:

```
function query_posts($query) {
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
    return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($query);
}
```

It break link between `$wp_query` and `$wp_the_query`. And the reverse can be performend by `wp_reset_query()` to re-establish that:

```
function wp_reset_query() {
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

So main query is the one that WP set up during core load.

It is typically what `$wp_query` holds, unless it was modified not to be main query anymore.