# What is "main query"?

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know which one is the main query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80454/how-to-know-which-one-is-the-main-query)

I'm curious to know what is the so called "main query"?

What I have is two queries on front page.

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    // do the main loop
endwhile; endif;

$posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'some_other_post_type'));
while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();
    // do the secondary loop
    // but still operating with the some_post_type
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```

And what I want is just to modify the main query to my custom post type for efficiency.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'some_name');
function some_name($query) {
    if (is_front_page() && is_main_query()) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'some_post_type' );
        return;
    }
}
```

What I thought is that condition in that hook will be true only for the first loop, but it appears that any `new WP_Query` is passing through it.

Can you explain me, please, what is "main query" and what is not?

*PS: I've found [almost a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52480/using-pre-get-posts-with-wp-query) with the solution to vary the queries in `pre_get_post` hook by custom query vars.*

Comment: I suggest reading this http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-portland-2011

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The filter has a bug in it, namely when it calls `is_main_query`, it's not checking if the passed `$query` is the main query, it's checking if the *currently active query* is the main query, which will always be true.

So instead try this:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_frontpage_main_query' );
function modify_frontpage_main_query( \WP_Query $query ) : void {
    if ( $query->is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'some_post_type' );
    }
}
```

Comment: **Tom, thank you so much!** Yeah that was the exact problem: I just forgot to call those functions from `$query`.

Answer (score 4):

The main query is the one triggered automatically when WordPress has determined what to show for the request URI.

Later instances of `WP_Query` are never the main query, but you can use them to replace the main query’s result in `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`. **Don’t do that.**