# Why my query is not "Main_query"?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I made a new page in admin panel like this. I want my Query here to be main_query so the other plugins could hook it, modify limits, etc...

```
add_action('admin_menu', function (){
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=ticket', __('Board', 'askanban'), __('Board', 'askanban'), 'edit_posts', 'askanban', array( $this, 'askanban_display_board' ), 1);
});

public function askanban_display_board(){
        $args = array(
            'post_type'              => 'ticket',
            'posts_per_page'         => - 1,
        );
        $query =  new \WP_Query( $args );
        $query->is_main_query(); // FALSE HERE!!!!!!!
        $posts = $query->posts;
        print_r($posts);
}
```

I read tons of info like this [How to know which one is the main query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80454/how-to-know-which-one-is-the-main-query) , this https://wp-qa.com/can-i-set-my-wp_query-to-be-a-main-query or [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)
I tried to use `get_posts()` and even tried to set `$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new \WP_Query( $args )` or `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] = new \WP_Query( $args );`
Noting helps.  The other plugin can't see this query as "main". For this "other plugin" there is no main query on this page. Why?

Comment: The main query is the WP core query running for the page. I doubt you can replace, there should be no need to replace it, and I'm certain that you shouldn't replace it.

Comment: But for now my page has no main query. Let's ask another way: "How to make main  query for custom page in Wordpress?" What is "the best practice" for it? I don't want to make a workaround. This query should be a real main loop.

Answer (score 0):

And the anwser to my question: Don't make new WP_Query object. Don't try to overwrite main query. Use global $wp_query; In my example the function should be like this:

```
public function askanban_display_board(){
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set('post_type', 'ticket');
    $wp_query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
    $posts = $wp_query->get_posts();
    print_r($posts);
}
```